# Switch that is rated for 24 V and 4 A: can it endure 8 A if I limit the voltage?

Tags: power, switches, safety, amperage, volts

I have a switch that is rated for 24 V and 4 A. Can this switch endure 8 A if I limit  voltage? What voltage would I have to limit to? My concern would be not to melt the switch with too much power. Power should be the same for 24 V, 4 A and 12 V, 8 A, hence they generate the same amount of heat. That's my understanding so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how voltage drop works.

You're right that 24V/4A and 12V/8A is the same useful power *at the final point-of-use*.  However, enroute is another matter entirely.

### Devices are not perfect

You notice that when we draw wires and switches in schematics, we simply presume they are zero ohms and have zero voltage drop.  Wouldn't that be nice!  But in fact they do have voltage drop because they have resistance.

> Imagine your switch is 0.01 ohms when connected.  If you flow 4 amps across it, what is that? V=IR so Vdrop = 4 * 0.01 or 0.04 volts drop.
>
> How much power is that?  0.04 volts x 4 amps = 0.16 watts that is directly causing heat in the switch.  Supposedly the switch is rated for this.
>
> OK, now imagine you flow 8 amps across the same switch.  V=IR.  Vdrop = 8 * 0.01 or 0.08 volts drop.  That's double the voltage drop **so double the power/heat, right?**
>
> 0.08 volts x 8 amps = 0.64 watts **Yikes! That's 4 times! It's not double at all!** No wonder the switch deosn't like it.

So you see that exceeding a device's current rating is **quadratically more destructive** to the device.  Exceeding it by even a little is dumb.

What's more, if you're using cheap Cheese from a certain far east Asian nation, even the rated current is probably highly optimistic. If anything you should be significantly derating those products.

### Why doesn't the switch care about voltage?

Did you notice that nothing in this conversation mentioned the supply voltage of 12 volts vs 24 volts?

Because when the switch is closed and current is flowing through it, the two terminals are almost at the same voltage. So the switch is not aware of the voltage at all.

Answer (score 7):

A switch that's rated for 24V and 4A means that it is designed to have 24V across it *when it is open*, and 4A going through it *when it is closed*.  Neither of these figures should be exceeded.

The whole *point* of a switch is that it is low resistance when it's closed, so the voltage across it when it's flowing 4A should be *significantly* lower than the voltage across it when it's opened.  I would expect millivolts, or perhaps a few tens of millivolts.

You just need to get a switch with better ratings, or use a switch to drive a relay, which actually switches the current you want.

Answer (score 2):

Often, switch current ratings are based on heating of the switch.

For example let's say you run the switch at 4 amps and it rises from 25 C initially to 50 C steady state. And you decide that is acceptable. So you call it a 4 Amp switch based on a 25 C temperature rise.

Heating is proportional to power loss in the switch which is proportional to the square of current. So if you double the current from 4 amps to 8 amps, the temperature rise will quadruple from 25 C to 100 C. So now, with 8 amps passing through it, it will rise from 25 C initially to 125 C. So, doubling the current is a big deal. It is actually even a little worse because conductive metals generally have a positive temperature coefficient of resistance. So as the switch gets hot, its resistance will go up, too.

There is always the chance that the switch rating is overly conservative. If you really want to know whether it is OK, you can test it at 8 amps under controlled conditions and make sure it does not overheat. You can also try turning it on and off a few times and carefully inspecting the internal contacts for wear or damage from arcing. If you are not willing and able to test it to your requirements, then stick to switches which are rated for how you are using them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this applies here but another consideration is the break current. If an unsafe condition is caused by failure to open the contacts...  well, that's not good. Sometimes it's a little more difficult to find this rating in the specs.